# Button in div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Initially my div (with the button inside) is hidden, when I press a button I make 10 clones of that div.

I want to be able to use each of the buttons seperatly (they all have the same attributes and class). At the moment I cannot use the any of the buttons.

```
 <div class="search-result">
                        <h3>Titel(year)</h3>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning btnFavorite">Favorite</button>
                        <button id="btnArkiv" class="btn btn-warning btnFAvorite">Arkiv</button>
  </div>

$(".btnFavorite").on("click", function(){
    alert("hej");
    var input = $("#search").val();
    saveFavorite(favoriteMovie);
});
```

Method to clone the div x times.

```
for(movie in search){
    console.log(search[movie].Title);
    favoriteMovie = search[movie].Title;
    $(".search-result:first").clone().appendTo(".search").find('h3').text(search[movie].Title);
    $('#your_element').attr('id','the_new_id');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Go look up _event delegation_.

Comment: Don't use input type submit for buttons. Use a simple <button> element unless you're actually submitting a form. So use normal buttons and delegate the event handler somewhere. Somthing like `$( "body" ).on( "click", ".btnFavorite", function(){ ... });`

Comment: You need to have enough code in your question to replicate the problem. Right now if I paste the first section of code in a fiddle, the alert works.

Comment: Thanks I've edited the question to correct buttons now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've replaced the input elements with actual buttons and delegated the event to the body, so that newly inserted movie buttons automatically use the same event handler. The div cloning function can also use some updates, but it should work and that's not the question. :)

You might have to update any function that uses the value as well, since it's a data-value attribute now. Hope it helps.

PS: I don't usually use jQuery, so untested and there might be syntax errors.

```html
<div class="search-result">
    <h3>Titel(year)</h3>
    <button data-value="Favoritfilm" class="btn btn-warning btnFavorite">buttonText</button>
    <button id="btnArkiv" data-value="Arkiv" class="btn btn-warning">buttonText</button>
 </div>
```

```js
$("body").on("click", ".btnFavorite", function() {
    alert("hej");
    var input = $("#search").val();
    saveFavorite(favoriteMovie);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! On a side question, is there a way to get h3 from the div where the button I just clicked?
as in something like `$("this").find("h3");` inside the button function? Since there is multiple buttons with the same class declaration.

Comment: Try `$("this").parent().find("h3");` since the 'this' element will probably be the button. Else use the event.target `function( event ) { ... $(event.target.parentNode).find("h3") ... }`

Comment: As long as the structure remains the same, `h3` is a sibling element that immediately proceeds `.btnFavorite`, you can use the `prev()` method in jQuery, i.e. `$( this ).prev()`. You can optionally provide it a selector to match against to make sure it selects/returns an `h3`, i.e. `$( this ).prev( 'h3' )`.

Comment: Will `.prev()` return 'empty text nodes' generated by whitespace in some browsers? Hence I didn't dare suggesting it directly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using click event without using the right ID. 
$(".btnFavorite") here you need to use the right ID, which is related to the button you are going to activate. In this case "btnArkiv".

Comment: There is two buttons, one with the id btnArkiv and the other one has the class btnFavorite.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var movieList = [
      {
        'ID': 1,
        'title': 'Movie 1',
        'year': 1988
      },
      {
        'ID': 2,
        'title': 'Movie 2',
        'year': 2017
      }
    ];

$(".btnFavorite").on("click", function(){
    alert("hej");
    var input = $("#search").val();
    saveFavorite(favoriteMovie);
});

$(".btnAdd").click(function() {
  for(index in movieList){    
    $(".list").append("<div class='search-result' data-id=" + movieList[index].ID + "><h3>" + movieList[index].title + " (" + movieList[index].year + ")</h3><button class='btn btn-warning btnFavorite' data-action='favoritize-id-" + movieList[index].ID + "'>Favorite Movie " + movieList[index].ID + "</button></div>");
  }
});
```

```css
.search-result {
    background-color: #EEE;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.search-result h3 {
    display: inline-block;
}

.search-result button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-warning btnAdd">Show Movie List</button>

<div class="list"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for `.on` this is why you are finding that only your first set of buttons work after cloning the result 10 times:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, place scripts after the elements in the HTML markup or perform event binding inside a document ready handler. Alternatively, use delegated events to attach event handlers.

You can read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Since there isn't much information to go on, one way you can make all of your buttons use the same event handler is by using event delegation as CBroe mentioned in the comments.

Check out the snippet I have here with all the buttons working.

```js
$(".search").on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('btnFavorite')) {
    alert('hej');
  }
});

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $(".search-result:first").clone().appendTo(".search");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <div class="search-result">
    <h3>Titel(year)</h3>
    <input type="submit" value="Favoritfilm" class="btn btn-warning btnFavorite">
    <input id="btnArkiv" type="submit" value="Arkiv" class="btn btn-warning">
  </div>
</div>
```

In the snippet, I put a listener on the parent container and then check that the clicked target is the correct button before alerting.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, it's like Shilly answered. But I was going to ask, Is there a way to get the h3 element from the button I just pressed, since there is 10 different buttons with same listener.

Comment: When you click, you can use the event target as a starting point to find your title. For example, you can look at the parent of the button that you clicked and then grab the `h3` tag from there using `$(e.target).parent().find('h3')`.